# Python v3, not listing radio buttons in tkinter grid properly

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to run a basic gui with some widgets (labels, entry boxes, radio buttons etc...) I've ordered these widgets in a tkinter window using the common grid method (e.g row =1, column =1)

However this piece of code here:

```
    Label(self,
          text = "Customer's Phone Number:",
          ).grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.cusPhone = Entry(self)
    self.cusPhone.grid(row = 9, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.breadType_var = IntVar()
    self.breadType_var.set(0)

    Label(self,
          text = "Bread Type ($2):",
          ).grid(row = 10, column = 0, sticky = W)

    breadType = ["White", "Wheat", "Toasted Herbs"]

    self.breadType_btns = []
    for i in range(len(breadType)):
        rb = Radiobutton(parent, variable = self.breadType_var, value = i, anchor = W, text = breadType[i], command=self.show_sentence)
        self.breadType_btns.append(rb)
        rb.grid(row = i , column = 1)

    Label(self,
          text = "Cheeses ($1):",
          ).grid(row = 16, column = 0, sticky = W)
```

Particuarly looking at the breadType list... down till rb.grid is where I think the problem lies. It's almost like its making a second grid: rb.grid() on top of my first grid: self.grid()

When I run code, radio buttons appear on side...

[image: First Output]

Can anyone help me fix my code so that the radio buttons appear either below the label Bread Type or horizontally next to the label?

P.S I'm using a class which has 'parent' passed into this function.

EDIT: Now it displays this:

[image: Second Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's almost like itsenter image description here making a second grid: rb.grid() on top of my first grid: self.grid()

That is a true statement.

The radio buttons have a different parent than the labels. While it's impossible to know what you're really trying to accomplish, my guess is that the radiobuttons should have a parent of `self` rather than `parent` since that's what the label widgets use as a parent.

For example:

```
for i in range(len(breadType)):
    rb = Radiobutton(self, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. However the radio buttons still seem to be on the right hand/top side of the gui. Any way to set a column value to keep to the left while having 'i' display with the column value (row will be = 11).

Comment: I used (row=(1 + i) to get around this and sticky = W. Problem solved!